# Выделение SQL запросов в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Осуществил в `PHPStorm` подключение к своей базе данных. Подключение состоялось успешно.

Структура моих таблиц теперь отображается во вкладке `Database (View -> Tool Windows -> Database)`.

Однако, все мои `SQL запросы` выделяются желтым, а `таблицы и столбцы` - красным. IDE ссылается на то, что нет таких таблиц и столбцов, и предлагает создать. Хотя во вкладке `Database` эти же самые таблицы и столбцы есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать это выделение желтым и сделать, чтобы IDE "увидела" внутри SQL запросов таблицы и столбцы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во вкладке "Resolution Scopes" необходимо выбрать, какая система управления базами данных должна использоваться для текущего проекта. Это решает проблему с выделением SQL запросов желтым цветом и выделением таблиц и столбцов красным.